# Tomcat manager username and password failed

Tags: tomcat

I have tomcat 5.x installed and is running on port 80(with mod_jk setup). The directories 'manager', 'examples' and 'ROOT' were removed under /usr/share/tomcat/webapps/ and rebuilt them copying from a working tomcat server. When I acces http://localhost:8080/manager/html (or) http://localhost/manager/html, it keeps on prompting for the password even after enter correct username and password.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the passwords are correct?

Check the `TOMCAT_HOME/conf/tomcat-users.xml` to see if the user has `roles="manager"` assigned

Answer (score 0):

For your tomcat-users.xml use this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<tomcat-users>
  <role rolename="tomcat"/>
  <role rolename="role1"/>
  <role rolename="manager"/>
  <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,manager"/>
  <user username="role1" password="tomcat" roles="role1"/>
  <user username="both" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,role1"/>
</tomcat-users>
```